Cumulative incidence function - compare time at which a specific cumulative incidence is reached
I have survival data and I've plotted cumulative incidence functions stratified by treatment status (with age as the time scale). I used Gray's test to compare the overall cumulative incidence functions, and I've compared cumulative incidence at a specific age/time. I'd also like to compare the age at which a given incidence is reached. For example, I'd like to estimate the age at which both groups reach a cumulative incidence of 25% and compare the ages to ask whether the untreated group reaches a cumulative incidence of 25% significantly earlier than the treated group. I can identify the age at which a 25% cumulative incidence is reached for each group from the cumulative incidence functions, but I'm not sure how to calculate the variance/conduct the hypothesis testing. Is it possible to calculate this from the cumulative incidence functions?

Is this a single-event incidence analysis or a competing-risks situation?

This is a single-event incidence analysis. Though I'm also curious about this in a competing-risks framework, as that may be a follow up analysis.

If there is only a single event type and there is at most one event per individual, then the cumulative incidence is simply the complement of the survival function. A cumulative incidence of 25% is equivalent to a survival probability of 75%. Although you used Gray's test, in that scenario I recall that it's equivalent to the log-rank test.
This page outlines some issues in comparing quantiles of survival times between groups. It specifically addresses the median, but the principles apply to any quantile. It's fairly straightforward to get confidence intervals for a quantile for an individual group, but comparisons among groups are more involved.
Brookmeyer and Crowley, in Journal of the American Statistical Association, 77: 433-440, 1980, proposed a test based on determining the median of the pooled data and determining how many individuals in each group exceeded that value. They provided ways to weight observations to get an appropriate median and to handle censoring. Their statistic asymptotially follows a chi-square distribution with 1 degree of freedom if 2 groups are compared. Chen and Zhang, in BMC Medical Research Methodology, 16: Article number  33, 2016, discussed limitations of that and other methods and proposed an alternative.
In practice, it might be most straightforward to use resampling for hypothesis testing. For example, the controlTest package in R uses bootstrapping to perform 2-sample comparisons of survival quantiles with right censoring. Or you might get an estimate of the null distribution of group differences in the time of reaching a quantile by repeatedly permuting the group labels among individuals.
Be careful if you intend to extend this to a competing-risks scenario, however. If you simply ask the R survival package to get survival quantiles for a multi-state model like a competing-risks model, you get an error message: "quantiles are not a well defined quantity for multi-state models."
A further warning:
It's not clear how you "stratified by treatment status (with age as the time scale)." If there's a treatment involved, one typically uses the date of treatment start as the time = 0 reference in survival analysis and time after treatment as the time scale. In that case, age at treatment might be included as a covariate.
"With age as the time scale," however, suggests something different: using date of birth (or some other fixed age) as time = 0. Sometimes an age time scale makes a lot of sense and one might, for example, include treatment as a time-varying covariate. But that would complicate your interpretation of cumulative incidence quantiles: if people received treatment at different ages, the age at which the event occurred would presumably be affected by the age at which treatment was begun.
Furthermore, you would have to deal with the left truncation of event times. A person entering the study at, say, age 50 provides no information about individuals younger than 50, many of whom might have experienced the event and not be available for study enrollment. That can be handled by the "counting process" data format and appropriate software but it typically leads to problems arising from having little data for early times. See this page or others available from a search for "left truncation"
